# Error adding methods to a class that conform to NSComparisonMethods protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to extend a Fraction class by adding couple of methods that conform to NSComparisonMethods protocol.

This is my code:
Fraction.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol NSComparisonMethods

-(BOOL) isEqualTo:(id)object;
-(BOOL) isLessThanOrEqualTo:(id)object;
-(BOOL) isLessThan:(id)object;
-(BOOL) isGreaterThan:(id)object;
-(BOOL) isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:(id)object;
-(BOOL) isNotEqualTo:(id)object;

@end

@interface Fraction : NSObject <NSComparisonMethods>

@property int numerator, denumerator;

-(void) print: (BOOL) test;
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d;
-(double) convertToNum;
-(void) reduce;
-(id) addFrac:(id)f;
-(void) justPrint;
-(id) initWith:(int)n over:(int)f;
+(Fraction *) allocF;
+(int) count;
+(int) gCounter;

@end
```

Fraction.m

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction

@synthesize numerator, denumerator;

-(BOOL) isEqualTo:(id)object
{
    Fraction *selfCopy = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    if (selfCopy == object) 
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}
//more methods..
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Fraction.h"
#import "Fraction+MathOperations.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        Fraction *fracA = [[Fraction alloc] init];
        Fraction *fracB = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        id Object;

        [fracA setTo:1 over:4];
        [fracB setTo:1 over:4];

        Object = fracB;

        NSLog(@"%s",[fracA isEqualTo: Object]? "Yes":"No");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Isn't it suppose to work properly? Im getting `No` no metter what..
Is the problem in the method implementation? cant I test object like this `(selfCopy == object)`? should I do `selfCopy.numerator` (exedra..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (selfCopy == object)
```

this only checks, if the pointer is the same

try

```
-(BOOL) isEqualTo:(id)object
{
    return self.numerator == object.numerator && self.denumerator == object.denumerator :
}
```

Okay, this is too simple, as `[fracA setTo:1 over:4]` and `[fracA setTo:2 over:8]` should probably be equal, but you should get the point.

---

> The default implementation provided for many of these methods by NSObject is appropriate for objects that implement a single comparison method whose selector, signature, and description match the following:
>
> > ```
> > - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(id)object;
> > ```
>
> This method should return NSOrderedAscending if the receiver is less than object,
>   NSOrderedDescending if the receiver is greater than object, and
>   NSOrderedSame if the receiver and object are equal. For example,
>   NSString does not implement most of the methods declared in this
>   informal protocol, but NSString objects still handle messages
>   conforming to this protocol properly because NSString implements a
>   compare: method that meets the necessary requirements. Cocoa also
>   includes appropriate compare: method implementations for the NSDate,
>   NSDecimalNumber, and NSValue classes.

So you should better have a `-compare:` like

```
-(NSOrderResult) compare:(Fraction *)otherFraction
{
    Fraction *selfReduced = [self fractionReduced]; // should return a unretaind reduced copy
    Fraction *otherReduced= [otherFraction fractionReduced];
    float selfAbs = (float)selfReduced.nominator / (float)selfReduced.denominator;
    float otherAbs = (float)selfReduced.nominator / (float)selfReduced.denominator;
    if (selfAbs > otherAbs) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (selfAbs > otherAbs) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Comment: what did you mean about "You do not need to redeclare the NSComparisonMethods"?@vikingosegundo

Comment: this is the only place they are declared..@vikingosegundo

Comment: see the first block in the question

Comment: what is compare? @vikingosegundo

Comment: you should implement NSobject's `-isEqual:` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCCECDG

Answer (score 2):

`if (selfCopy == object)` will always be false, because you are comparing pointers.

You have to implement a proper comparison of your instances.

> cant I test object like this (selfCopy == object)? should I do selfCopy.numerator

No. You don't need a copy of `self`. Also, you're not even creating a copy of `self`, you're only allocating a new object. This is how it should look like.

```
-(BOOL)isEqualTo:(id)object
{
    if (self.someValue == object.someValue &&
        self.otherValue == object.otherValue) 
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: You can just write `return (self.someValue == object.someValue &&
        self.otherValue == object.otherValue);` as well.

Comment: Sure, I just didn't want to change the original code too much.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
-(BOOL) isEqualTo: (Fraction *) f
{
Fraction *temp1 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
Fraction *temp2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
[temp1 setTo:[self numerator] over:[self denominator]];
[temp2 setTo:[f numerator] over:[f denominator]];
[temp1 reduce];
[temp2 reduce];

return ([temp1 numerator] == [temp2 numerator])
        && ([temp1 denominator] == [temp2 denominator]);
}
```