# Problems using protocols

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I am new to programming and have been working through "Programming in Objective C" to try and get started. I am currently doing the exercises in chapter 11 and am stuck with exercise 11.3

This exercise is asking me to:

"Extend the Fraction class by adding methods that conform to the informal protocol NSComparisonMethods, as listed earlier in this chapter.
Implement the first six methods from that protocol (isEqualTo:, isLessThanOrEqualTo:, isLessThan:,
isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:, isGreaterThan:, isNotEqualTo:) and test them."

However I am unsure how to use apple protocols. I have found many tutorials on how to define my own protocols but none on how to use apples already predefined protocols.

Sorry for the beginner question but I have searched for the past 2 days and haven't found and answer yet. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another response to the same, or very similar question.

[Error adding methods to a class that conform to NSComparisonMethods protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970395/error-adding-methods-to-a-class-that-conform-to-nscomparisonmethods-protocol)

Comment: Thanks for the responseI saw that one. So even if you are using apple's protocols you still have to write them all out again, you cant just import a file and say that you are going to adhere to the protocols (i.e. <ProtocolName>)

Answer (score 0):

Objective C's protocols are analogs of interfaces in Java, C#, etc.
If your class implements protocol it should implement all methods of this protocol defined as @required.
In protocol all methods are @required by default.